# Sapper/Svelte/Rollup external dependencies best practice?

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg, svelte, rollupjs, sapper

Smart people!

I’m a bundler-beginner with a bundler slash dependency-question.

- On `yarn dev run` I get the error: *"Cannot find module '@sveltejs/svelte-scroller'..."*
- I have a sapper/svelte/rollup/yarn-suite
- the [svelte-scroller](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sveltejs/svelte-scroller)-plugin

The plugin is by default loaded as an external in rollup.config.js:

```
{ ..., server: { ..., external: <**package.json-dependencies-arr**> } ... }
```

And when I use it in a .svelte-component:

```
import Scroller from '@sveltejs/svelte-scroller';

//...

<Scroller />
```

...the error slaps my face.

### Notes

- rollup.config.js is unchanged from the template clone
- If I remove the plugin from the dependencies-arr loaded as externals in rollup.config.js **the error goes away**.
- ...which tells me that rollup *shouldn't* load the dependency as an external (assuming the only goal is to make the specified error vanish).
- And since svelte-scroller's purpose here is client-interaction-related, I presume it shouldn't be a part of the bundle either way.
- Of course cyberspace has related issues, but I can't seem to find a clear best practice example on how to handle this.
- My current workaround is therefore:

  ```
   // in rollup.config.js
   import pkg from './package.json';

   // filter out those "not external dependencies" 
   const notExternals = ['@sveltejs/svelte-scroller'];
   const externals = Object.keys(pkg.dependencies).filter(plugin =>
       notExternals.some(not => not === plugin) ? false : true
   );

   export default {
       // ...,
       server: {
           // ...,
           // bundle filtered externals (along with default built in modules)
           external: externals.concat(require('module').builtinModules),
       },
       // ...
   }
  ```

And if the error revisits with another dependency, I'll just add it to the notExternals-arr.

### Question

1. **Considering the sapper/svelte/rollup-setup, is this approach best practice when handling client-based plugins causing similar errors?**

Thanks in advance!

### Stack

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:896
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '@sveltejs/svelte-scroller'
Require stack:

    - /.../__sapper__/dev/server/server.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:893:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:743:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:965:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/.../__sapper__/dev/server/server.js:8:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1076:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:941:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:782:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/.../__sapper__/dev/server/server.js'
  ]
}
```

### Reproduce if you dare

template

```
npx degit "sveltejs/sapper-template#rollup" <app-name>
```

plugin

```
yarn add @sveltejs/svelte-scroller
```

import the plugin to a .svelte-component

```
<script>
   import Scroller from '@sveltejs/svelte-scroller';
</script>

//...

<Scroller />
```

go

```
yarn run dev
```

Comment: Hi @Kiiim, this is a very good question except for one point: you should try to ask a single question; preferably whose answer doesn't involve personal opinion. This makes the question easier to answer and to the point, which can also benefit other people with similar issues.

Comment: @guzmonne yeah, it's sooo hard to keep things concise when your questions feels chained. But I agree, edited :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `@sveltejs/svelte-scroller` is a Svelte component rather than a JS module, it must be processed by the Svelte compiler at build time rather than imported at runtime. In other words, it *should* be part of your bundle.

The conventional way to do this, if the contents of `dependencies` are treated as `external`, is to add the package to `devDependencies` instead:

```
yarn add -D @sveltejs/svelte-scroller
```

Comment: Of all responses, this clearly stands out!
Jokes aside, dressing all similar non js-modules as devDeps apparently works. And yeah, it seems kind of logical to let the compiler do its work. Also the word ”conventional” gives me inner peace when moving forward with this approach. Thanks sir @Rich.